# python pandas sum value based on date&string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, lambda

Given the 2 dataframes

```
df1
Year Month Day Name value
2022 2     11  ADP1 5,3
2022 2     15  ADP2 300,2
2022 3     21  ADP1 7000,3
2022 3     25  ADP2 13,2
2022 8     15  ADP1 444,1
2022 8     5   ADP2 3333,2
```

```
df2
Name1  Name2  Date1      Date2
xx     APD1   2022-02-23 2022-04-30 
yy     APD2   2022-05-23 2022-06-30
zz     APD1   2022-07-01 2022-09-01
ww     APD2   2022-07-15 2022-09-30
```

I want to have the following output

```
out
Name1  Name2  Date1      Date2       sum
xx     APD1   2022-02-03 2022-04-30  7005,6
yy     APD2   2022-05-23 2022-06-30  0
zz     APD1   2022-07-01 2022-09-01  444,1
ww     APD2   2022-07-15 2022-09-30  3333,2
```

In words: compare Name2 in df2 with Name in df1, check if (Year,Month,Date) is in range of Date1, Date2, then sum each value

Right now I'm iterating over Year, months with a for loop and currently in the process to add another for loop for days...
I'm pretty sure there is a neat(er) way in pandas. I*m fiddling with lambda x: with no success (still learning). can someone help me find the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one date in df2 2022-02-23, and in the expected result it is 2022-02-03. I fixed it. Also, in your df1, the value column has a fractional part in the form of a comma, which I replaced with a dot, as is the case in most cases, and converted the column type to float. Based on this, I assume that all your data is of a string type, so I made them all like that. Of the three columns df1, one column with the date has been created:

```
pd.to_datetime(df1[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
```

The date columns of both frames are converted from string to date.

To summarize the result, a list generator is used (it is much faster than a loop). Three conditions are used to filter at each iteration. The list result 'aaa' is stored in a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Year': ['2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022'], 'Month': ['2', '2', '3', '3', '8', '8'],
     'Day': ['11', '15', '21', '25', '15', '5'],
     'Name': ['ADP1', 'ADP2', 'ADP1', 'ADP2', 'ADP1', 'ADP2'],
     'value': ['5,3', '300,2', '7000,3', '13,2', '444,1', '3333,2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name1': ['xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'ww'], 'Name2': ['ADP1', 'ADP2', 'ADP1', 'ADP2'],
     'Date1': ['2022-02-03', '2022-05-23', '2022-07-01', '2022-07-15'],
     'Date2': ['2022-04-30', '2022-06-30', '2022-09-01', '2022-09-30']})

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
df2[['Date1', 'Date2']] = df2[['Date1', 'Date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df1['value'] = df1['value'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)

aaa = [df1.loc[(df1['Date'] >= df2.loc[i, 'Date1']) & (df1['Date'] <= df2.loc[i, 'Date2']) &
               (df1['Name'] == df2.loc[i, 'Name2']), 'value'].sum() for i in range(len(df2))]

df2['sum'] = aaa
```

Output

```
  Name1 Name2      Date1      Date2     sum
0    xx  ADP1 2022-02-03 2022-04-30  7005.6
1    yy  ADP2 2022-05-23 2022-06-30     0.0
2    zz  ADP1 2022-07-01 2022-09-01   444.1
3    ww  ADP2 2022-07-15 2022-09-30  3333.2
```

More details on the 'aaa' list:

1.(df1['Date'] >= df2.loc[i, 'Date1']) at each iteration, a row (not a column, that is, one value) from df2.[Date1'] is selected and compared with the column df1['Date'].

2.(df1['Date'] <= df2.loc[i, 'Date2']) the same as the first condition.

3.(df1['Name'] == df2.loc[i, 'Name2']) similarly, only here the string value is checked for a match.

All conditions are concatenated with &, which means the same as in python and. Get a boolean mask, where True is what matched. We use it as an index, to access the desired values. This is what is on the left, and on the right we specify the desired column 'value'.
Pseudo code for better understanding:

```
df1.loc[index, 'value'].sum()
```

The list generator at each iteration writes the result of each iteration to the list.
loc means that explicit indexing is used, where, as already mentioned, indexes (rows) are indicated on the left, and the column name on the right. You can specify multiple indexes by enclosing them in square brackets.
For example like this:

```
df1.loc[[0, 2, 3], 'value']]
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Works as intended.

But im actually more interested in the way (i wasnt expecting a fully working solution to be honest :D ).

Could you elaborate your thoughts / the way you came to the solution?

I really like how human readable the ` aaa = ...`  actually is

Comment: @Side2005 added more details to the answer.